# Ruby version from homebrew doesn't match computer version

Tags: ruby, homebrew

I'm not trying to manage multiple versions of Ruby although I think that's what I have.

When I run `ruby -v` it says `ruby 2.3.0p0 (2015-12-25 revision 53290) [x86_64-darwin15]`.

However, when I ran `brew upgrade ruby` it says Ruby didn't exist. Then I did `brew install ruby` and it installed version 2.4.0. When I run `ruby -v` it still says the same thing.

How do I just have the most up to date version of Ruby on my computer?

I have a Mac.

Comment: brew install ruby, should do it, although I don't know if some other command altered your ruby config/installation

Comment: can you run `which ruby` and post the response?

Comment: Mac OS comes with Ruby built-in because Apple uses it for some of their code. We can use it but shouldn't mess with it. RVM, rbenv or Homebrew install Ruby(s) outside of the system so we're free to mess with them all we want. `ruby -v` is probably pointing to the system Ruby because you haven't pointed your path to the newly installed Ruby.

Comment: @eiko to respond to `which ruby` is `/Users/blueduckyy/.rbenv/shims/ruby`

Comment: Your Ruby is being managed by rbenv, which is a very good sandbox manager. You say that you used Homebrew, which is an alternate way of installing Ruby, or of installing rbenv which can then install Ruby. Which did you do? Either way, rbenv is not RVM so the suggestion in the selected answer to install and use RVM in addition isn't a good idea as those two are not compatible, and their simultaneous use will cause headaches for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because your PATH link to your origin ruby, you should add your homebrew ruby path to your .bash_profile like this `export PATH=${PATH}:${HOMEBREW_HOME}/ruby`

The better way that I recommend is using the rvm https://rvm.io/rvm/install

Follow the step to install rvm/ruby

`gpg --keyserver hkp://keys.gnupg.net --recv-keys 409B6B1796C275462A1703113804BB82D39DC0E3`

`\curl -sSL https://get.rvm.io | bash`

then copy and execute the shell in bash

`echo '[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm"' >> ~/.bashrc`

restart the bash and type `which ruby`, then it return `$HOME/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.3/bin/ruby` and your ruby work.

Comment: A path to a user installed Ruby should be before the original path: `~/path/to/ruby:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin`. If it's not the original Ruby will be found before the new one, continuing the problem.

Comment: @theTinMan, you are right, I don't describe the detail